# mpd not using lame or vorbis encoders

Tags: macos, encoder, lame, mpd

I am trying to run an httpd stream via mpd. The config I have is fairly straight forward:

```
# --------  AUDIO FOR STREAM ---------------------
audio_output {
    type          "httpd"
    name          "My HTTP Stream"
    encoder       "lame"        # optional, vorbis or lame
    port          "8000"
#    quality        "5.0"            # do not define if bitrate is defined
    bitrate       "128"            # do not define if quality is defined
#    format        "44100:16:1"
#    max_clients    "0"            # optional 0=no limit
}
```

However when I run mpd I get the following error:

```
Mar 28 15:40 : fatal_error: line 337: No such encoder: lame
```

The same occurs when I try using vorbis. I checked my version of mpd and this is the output:

```
$ mpd --version
Music Player Daemon 0.19.8
...
Encoder plugins:
  null wave
...
```

So as it stands it doesn't seem to have the lame/vorbis encoder plugin installed. I'm currently using OS X so i've installed mpd through homebrew. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason even though I had lame + vorbis libraries installed as dependencies, they weren't installed as encoder plugins when I installed mpd.

To do this you have to run the brew command with the encoders as options.

`brew install mpd --with-lame`